# iOS 8 custom Keyboard with custom font I created to be used across iOS apps?

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios8, ios8.1, ios8-extension

I have a working custom keyboard for iOS8, I can also use a custom font that I created for the keyboard keys however I would like to know if it is possible to enforce using this custom font within all of the applications such as notes, sms email, any app across the ios device?

Apology if this is a simple question but I have built a demo and I am not seeing my characters showing inside the notes app and I am just wondering if it is something that I am doing wrong or that it is not possible? Thank you.

Comment: Check that your custom font is working